# Is it possible to read iBooks without an iOS device?

Tags: macos, ios, books

I no longer have an iPhone or iPad, but still have books in my iTunes account that I would like to read. Is there a program for OS X that will allow me to read iBooks without an iOS device?

I am familiar with calibre, but the main issue here is the DRM.

Comment: No... now. There's speculation that Apple will be responding to Amazon's release of their Kindle reader with an OSX-based iBooks reader at Thursday's education-related event. So you may want to watch the details of whatever news comes out of that.

Comment: Sadly, this did not happen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OS X 10.9 Mavericks includes an iBooks app that allows you to read any documents - including purchased books or your own pdfs - that you had in iBooks for iOS.

Mavericks is a free upgrade available for the following systems, and was released on 22 October, 2013 through the Mac App Store.

From [OS X Mavericks : System Requirements](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5842?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

> To install Mavericks, you need one of these Macs:
>
> iMac (Mid-2007 or later) MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008),
>   (13-inch, Early 2009 or later) MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or
>   later), MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
>   MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later) Mac Mini (Early 2009 or later) Mac
>   Pro (Early 2008 or later) Xserve (Early 2009)  Your Mac also needs:
>
> OS X Mountain Lion, Lion, or Snow Leopard v10.6.8 already installed 2
>   GB or more of memory 8 GB or more of available space

Comment: One thing I like about the new iBooks app is that it has the ability to load my own ePub and pdf formatted work/books/documents, etc. I find that so useful, that I'm contemplating moving from kindle.app. I never thought I would.

Answer (score 17):

Apple has released an **[FAQ for iBooks](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4059)** where *(as of January 2012)*, it says under
 *About iBooks and the iBookstore → What are the requirements to use iBooks?:*

> You can use iBooks on iPad. You can also use iBooks on iPhone or iPod touch with iOS 4 or later.

Until OS X Mavericks was released with iBooks for OS X, the answer was **no**.

Comment: Answer correct at time of writing but answer is now yes with iBooks app in Mavericks

Answer (score 7):

At this time Unfortunately, no.

There is no Mac OS X application for iBooks.  You may want to submit a [feature request to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/ibooks_ios.html).

Comment: This is now available in OS X Mavericks. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98146/10033

Answer (score 1):

If you copy a purchased epub format book out to the Finder, you can load it into [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), but when you try to read it, the App's embedded reader tells you:

> This Book is locked by **DRM**. To learn more about DRM and why you cannot read or convert this book in calibre, [click here](http://drmfree.calibre-ebook.com/about#drm).

Apple has not yet provided a method to read these books on a Mac.
Despite rumor, Thursday's education-related event produced no OSX-based iBooks reader. So the answer is still no, and will likely remain no for the forseeable future.

Comment: Calibre will connect with your iTunes library, however iBooks are protected by DRM and not readable outside of the iBooks app.

Comment: No such announcement was made today at the Apple event, so the answers remains as 'No' for now.